# Добавить прогресс скачивания файла c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, download

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста.. как сделать так, чтобы отображался процесс скачивания файла в консоли?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define CURL_STATICLIB

#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"wldap32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "curl/libcurl.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

int main()
{
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
const char *url = "http://host/file.exe";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\file.exe";
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, например, во `write_data` какой-то вывод прогресса...

Comment: ...но если write_data вызывается всего один раз, то бесполезно. Нужно, чтобы буферно писало файл. То есть по кускам.

Comment: `write_data()` вызывается при каждом заполнении буфера размером `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE` полностью или на `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE` (оба 16k по умолчанию). Если это слишком много, то можно увеличить первый из них из них...